# How does ListenUriMode.Unique work for clients?

Tags: .net, wcf, sockets, port

I'm writing a WCF service, and am attempting to avoid getting `AddressAlreadyInUseException` when my port is already taken. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1291788/546561) points toward using [`ListenUriMode.Unique`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.listenurimode.aspx) to solve this problem.  From MSDN, it appears that this option would cause my service to automatically choose an available port:

> For TCP in exclusive mode (PortSharingEnabled is false) this means binding to a uniquely available port number.

My question is, if my port number is being chosen at runtime, how would my client know what port number to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456783%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to discover the service.