# How do I detect what application is listening on a given TCP port?

Tags: vb.net, tcp-port

How do I detect what application, if any, is listening on a given TCP port on Windows? Here's xampp doing this:

[image]

I'd prefer to do this in VB.NET, and I want to offer the user the option to close that app.

Comment: You can invoke `netstat -no` and parse its output.

Comment: Well thing is that i wont use netstat and such.. Im working on some project that is used to control apache mysql and few more apps, so i want to get in textbox after clicking start button like "Port 80 is used by APP NAME and Apache can't be started." ?

Comment: Not sure why this attracted so many downvotes.  It's a legitimate question with a better answer than Process.Start("netstat -no").  If a new user comes to the site and posts a question that can be improved, please follow the FAQ and help the user improve the question and/or tell him what's wrong with it.

Comment: Maybe because of my bad grammar :) Eric can u help me over mail?

Comment: @Onlykl: No, that would not benefit the wider community.  However, I did post a good answer to your question.

Comment: Yeah but it is C# and I do not understand it xD

Comment: [Hmm, where have it seen a similar question?..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902632/how-do-i-get-the-ports-opened-by-a-windows-service)

Comment: Onlykl, the main thing to take away from Eric's answer is the Win32 API call to use ([GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). You'll need to P/Invoke it; http://www.pinvoke.net is really helpful here.

Comment: @Onlykl: convert to VB.NET using free converters available out there?

Comment: @Neolisk: Actually looks like there are several older SO questions that point to the same Code Project article I found with Google.  Voting to close as dup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which PID listens on a given port in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577433/which-pid-listens-on-a-given-port-in-c-sharp) (walked back one more question)

Comment: @Onlykl: You can P/Invoke from VB.Net just as easily as from C#.  It would probably be better if you read up on P/Invoke and just use the C# code as a guide (check out what parameters you have to pass in, and what the return value looks like using that code).  There are also VB.Net to C# converters out there, but I have never used one.

Comment: - Rep me all but you did not help me at all really. You all just confused me much more.

Comment: Ok, how about this: 1) learn about [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx), then 2) learn about [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then put the two together, using http://pinvoke.net to skip the hard parts. I don't know how to make it simpler than that. Remember that not every task is as simple as it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim hostname As String = "server1"
Dim portno As Integer = 9081
Dim ipa As IPAddress = DirectCast(Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname)(0), IPAddress)
Try
    Dim sock As New System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp)
    sock.Connect(ipa, portno)
    If sock.Connected = True Then
        ' Port is in use and connection is successful
        MessageBox.Show("Port is Closed")
    End If

    sock.Close()
Catch ex As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
    If ex.ErrorCode = 10061 Then
        ' Port is unused and could not establish connection 
        MessageBox.Show("Port is Open!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End If
End Try
```

this helped me :)

Comment: I get an error that the protocol isn't supported for IPv6 addresses? It's trying to use `::1`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment on the accepted answer, but I would say that I think checking for an exception to occur is pretty bad practice!

I spent quite a while searching for a solution to a very similar problem, and was about to go down the P/Invoke GetExtendedTcpTable route when I happened upon `IPGlobalProperties`.
I haven't tested this properly yet, but something like this...

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

And then...

```
Dim hostname = "server1"
Dim portno = 9081
Dim ipa = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname)(0)
Try
  ' Get active TCP connections - the GetActiveTcpListeners is also useful if you're starting up a server...
  Dim active = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections
  If (From connection In active Where connection.LocalEndPoint.Address.Equals(ipa) AndAlso connection.LocalEndPoint.Port = portno).Any Then
    ' Port is being used by an active connection
    MessageBox.Show("Port is in use!")
  Else
    ' Proceed with connection
    Using sock As New Sockets.Socket(Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, Sockets.SocketType.Stream, Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp)
      sock.Connect(ipa, portno)
      ' Do something more interesting with the socket here...
    End Using
  End If

Catch ex As Sockets.SocketException
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I hope someone finds this useful quicker than I did!