# Weird issue regarding GetOwnerModuleFromTcpEntry when targeting x64

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, 64-bit, iphelper

Since I am a first time poster, I do apologize if I unintentionally left out any key piece of information, but here it goes.

**Background:** I am doing some testing to find out what the undocumented member array ‘OwningModuleInfo’ in [MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_MODULE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is and how it aid said function in determining what process owns the TCP endpoint. I have reached the conclusion that the first item in the array is the index of the service in the list of running services, which brings us to the weird issue. I am using Visual Studio 2012 (update 3) on Windows 7. The test app is running under UAC = requireAdministrator (asInvoker produces the same result, however).

**Problem:** When I target x64, then for some entries in the tcp table, [GetOwnerModuleFromTcpEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fails and returns “126 - The specified module could not be found.”. When I target Win32, this problem disappears. Since I know that this only happens when the entry is owned by a service, I tried the following dummy call just before the call to my test function (now targeting x64):

```
SC_HANDLE serviceManager = OpenSCManager(
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE);

CloseServiceHandle(serviceManager);

MyTestFunction(); // Prints the TCP table along with owner information
```

Now, it works just fine.  Take the call to OpenSCManager away again, and it fails. Tell me that this is not really messed up?

- I have reviewed every compiler and linker setting I could find.
- I have double checked so I am linking to the proper libraries.
- I created a C++/CLI version with identical code, which works fine both for Win32 and x64.

  - Checked for memory/alignment/pointer issues.

*Sample output from test run without dummy call*

```
Pid:   2896
Owner: Skype.exe

Pid:   848
Owner: Error 126 - The specified module could not be found.

Pid:   2896
Owner: Skype.exe

Pid:   3756
Owner: Error 126 - The specified module could not be found.
```

*With dummy call*

```
Pid:   2896
Owner: Skype.exe

Pid:   848
Owner: RpcSs

Pid:   2896
Owner: Skype.exe

Pid:   3756
Owner: WMPNetworkSvc
```

Short of this being a bug on Microsoft’ part, I am obviously missing something and I’m at the end of my rope. So if someone could nudge me in the right direction as to what I might be missing, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that advapi32.dll is not loaded. Said function seems to assume that advapi32.dll is loaded when calling it, which apparently is not always the case. I still do not know why advapi32.dll isn't loaded automatically, but I guess that is another question.

[See this thread on the MSDN forum.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d18416e-4bba-4803-8e54-3ef160c1fb4f/weird-error-returned-by-getownermodulefromtcpentry-when-targeting-x64)