# Can TCP and UDP sockets use the same port?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp

First of all, is there any problem with using both UDP and TCP on the same server?

Secondly, can I use the same port number?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same port number for both TCP and UDP.  Many protocols already do this, for example DNS works on udp/53 *and* tcp/53.

Technically the port pools for each protocol are completely independent, but for higher level protocols that can use either TCP or UDP it's convention that they default to the same port *number*.

When writing your server, bear in mind that the sequence of events for a TCP socket is much harder than for a UDP socket, since as well as the normal `socket` and `bind` calls you also have to `listen` and `accept`.

Furthermore that `accept` call will return a new socket and it's *that* socket that you'll then have to also poll for receive events.  Your server should be prepared to continue `accept`ing connections on the original socket whilst simultaneously servicing multiple clients each of which will be triggering receive events on their own sockets.

Comment: another example NetBIOS with UDP and TCP on 137-139

Comment: @Eric Fortis RFC 1700 is full of examples, let's not list them all shall we? ;-)

Comment: the official repository of port numbers is at http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers these days, but many of the dual udp/tcp entries are merely reservations, and don't indicate that the protocol actually uses both.  For example there's no implementation of HTTP over UDP, since HTTP requires a reliable transport. Both are registered to avoid confusion and prevent an unrelated protocol appearing to be port 80.

Comment: @EJP The ietf is full of RFCs, let's not list them all shall we? BTW just pointing out some ports everybody should know about.

Comment: @Eric I could list the two I've written... ;-)

Comment: @Eric Fortist why exactly should 'everybody know about' the NetBIOS port numbers?

Comment: Please post it as a question so you can grant me the answer

Comment: Something this answer does not explain: the 'port' semantic is specific to each protocol (but some might not have this semantic) of the transport level (OSI model level 4). So TCP has its own ports, which are interpreted by the TCP stack; UDP has its own ports, which are interpreted by the UDP stack. So to say, ports are not shared between UDP and TCP; it just happens that both protocols have the same definition of "ports" and that in order to simplify, we use the same port value for multiple connections of different types to the same service.

Comment: @moala yes, that's right - I might expand the answer slightly.

Comment: @moala can I access same port (e: 53) ,in same time via  UDP and TCP protocol ?

Comment: @uma yes, you can (if supported by the server).  That's the entire point of this question.

Answer (score 14):

Firstly,there is no problem using both tcp and udp on the server.

Secondly,we can have both UDP and TCP requests on same port ,because each request is identified by a quintuple contained by source IP ,Destination IP, Source Port, Destination Port, PROTOCOL(as protocol can be TCP or UDP).

Comment: The reason you state is often given but it is really meaningless.  There is no such thing as a UDP connection, and no context in which connections are considered regardless of the associated protocol. The fact is that ports are artefacts of TCP and UDP separately, and there is therefore no possibility of ever confusing them.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my fault.It's right that there is no connection using UDP.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick `nc` experiment showing that you can use the same port for TCP/UDP simultaneously**

Tested on Ubuntu 23.10, `nc` from the netcat-openbsd package, based on my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52351480/895245 we can launch a simple server that listens forever on TCP port 8000 with:

```
nc -kdl 8000
```

From `man nc` we know that the `-u` flag uses UDP instead of TCP, let's try and launch another listener at the same time with `-u` from another shell:

```
nc -kdlu 8000
```

And now, we can send messages to either TCP or UDP, and the correct listener will always get the message, for TCP:

```
echo asdf | nc localhost 8000
```

and for UDP:

```
echo asdf | nc -u localhost 8000
```

and the corresponding listener then prints `asdf` to stdout.

Another way to check that both are actually listening on the same port number but on different domains is:

```
sudo netstat -tupan | grep 8000
```

which gives:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000       0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN      214312/nc
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000       0.0.0.0:*                       227612/nc
```

There is however a complicating factor that I only learned about when writing this answer, if we launch another two listeners with and without `-u`:

```
nc -kdl 8000
nc -kdlu 8000
```

then this version of `nc` does not complain. This is because as we can see with `strace`, `bind` is done with `SO_REUSEPORT`, related threads:

- [How netcat can listen to the same port on the same host from two different terminals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570647/how-netcat-can-listen-to-the-same-port-on-the-same-host-from-two-different-termi)
- [How netcat can listen to the same port on the same host from two different terminals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570647/how-netcat-can-listen-to-the-same-port-on-the-same-host-from-two-different-termi)

So now that we have four `nc` running, `netstat` gives:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000          0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      237988/nc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000          0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      214312/nc
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000          0.0.0.0:*                   237673/nc
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000          0.0.0.0:*                   227612/nc
```

and when we send the requests, the TCP and the UDP requests are randomly routed to either one of the two of the listeners of the corresponding type.