# How to run tcp and udp on a single port at same time?

Tags: java, networking, network-protocols

I have a situation like I have to run UDP and TCP both on a single port at a time. This is because in my application at any time anyone can call for any protocol. So I need to continously check the incoming request and serve the request. Can anyone pls help me to get rid of this situation in java?

Comment: Same port can receive both requests, but I do't think you can differentiate them - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437383/tcp-and-udp-sockets-on-same-port

Comment: @ManimaranSelvan No. All UDP ports are different from all TCP ports regardless of the number. They occupy different namespaces. OP has to use two sockets, a TCP and a UDP. There is no such thing as 'differentiate' the request because they can never get confused in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

You can't check whether a request is TCP or UDP.  Instead you add a listener which is TCP and a listener which is UDP.  IMHO UDP is more useful if you use a broadcast or multi-cast address.

e.g.

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(12345);
DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(12345);
```

or

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(12345);
DatagramSocket ds = new MulticastSocket(new InetSocketAddress("224.224.1.1", 12345));
```

In both cases, tcp connections go to the `ServerSocket` and udp packets go to the `DatagramSocket`