# How can TCP/IP identify the correct socket when we bind for 2 different protocols on the same port

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, datagram

Researching and asking of course here I found out something that I did not know/realize before.
That a process can bind a specific port for two different protocols.
E.g. the same port `X` for `TCP` and `UDP`. (Any other well-known examples?)
But how is this possible?
I mean if I do `new DatagramSocket(6789);` and `new ServerSocket(6789);`
I assume I can accept both `TCP` and `UDP` in my program and just delegate to different classes. Right?
But how does this actually work? Does java understand if the client is using `TCP` or `UDP` and passes the socket to the appropriate class?

Comment: Nothing to do with Java; your OS knows  the difference between TCP and UDP.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176474/how-to-run-tcp-and-udp-on-a-single-port-at-same-time for java, and there's a number of other similar Q's in general

Comment: @BrianRoach:So somehow the implementation of the 2 classes register to the OS for their protocols and OS knows where to pass what connection?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. TCP and UDP are two completely different things. You'd have a `ServerSocket` for TCP and a `DatagramSocket` for UDP and handle each of them in the appropriate manner.

Comment: @BrianRoach: But the clients connect to the same port right?How does a  udp client is send to the proper class? I don't understand this

Comment: Again ... TCP and UDP are completely different things.  Using the same port number is irrelevant. UDP:6789 has absolutely nothing to do with TCP:6789 If a client sends a UDP packet ... it's a UDP packet. The server's network stack receives it as a UDP packet, and it's delivered to your process as a UDP packet.

Answer (score 2):

Ports exist within the namespace of the protocol. It isn't the same port, only the same port number.

Java has nothing todo with it either.