# Basic UDP & TCP Program

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to write a simple server that will listen for one set of messages on UDP and another set of messages on TCP. I have written the following code:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import socket 

#define UDP listening function
def UDPListen():
    Listening_UDP_Port = 300
    Listening_IP = "127.0.0.1"
    BUFFER_SIZE = 64

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # IPv4, UDP
    sock.bind((Listening_IP, Listening_UDP_Port))

    while True:
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print "UDP Messsage from address: ", address
        print "Message: ", data

# END UPDListen() FUCNTION


#define a TCP listening function
def TCPListen():
    Listening_TCP_Port = 300
    Listening_IP = "127.0.0.1"
    BUFFER_SIZE = 64

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # IPv4, TCP
    sock.bind((Listening_IP, Listening_TCP_Port))

    while True:
        sock.listen(1)
        conn, address = sock.accept()
        print "TCP connection from", address
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print "Mesage: ", data
        conn.close()

# END TCPListen() FUCNTION


# main function
def main():
    ThreadUDP = Thread(target=UDPListen)
    ThreadTCP = Thread(target=TCPListen)

    print "Starting Server..."
    ThreadUDP.start()
    ThreadTCP.start()
    print "Server Started!"

#END main() FUNCTION


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However when I run it in Python 2.7 it throws a wobbly, any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: I dont think you can run 2 servers on the same port ...

Comment: Ports below 1024 are reserved for programs that are running as root.  So either change your port numbers to something above 1024, or run the program as root (preferably the former).  FWIW I changed the port number to 3000 and then your program ran fine

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: @JoranBeasley There's no conflict. One's on the TCP port, the other one's on the UDP port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me on Windows it launches fine as it is.

For linux you'll have to run it as root or use `sudo`

e.g.

```
sudo python ./yourserver.py
```

Or else change your port number to 1024 or above.

It's ok that they have the same port number. If it were 2 `tcp` service though it wouldn't be ok. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437383/can-tcp-and-udp-sockets-use-the-same-port).

Edit:

Given the OP's clarification of the real issue the solution is to use.

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

After creating the sockets. Where sock is your socket name.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I realised this morning that it was because the server doesn't close the ports when the process is killed it. So I had to restart the machine. Will need to find a nice way to close it down when its finished. Thanks again.