# C# Sockets (TCP & UDP)

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-4.0, tcp, udpclient

I'll cut to the point, I've been stuck on this for a few hours now. Tons of Google and tons of research but not straight answer as of yet.

I have a client and a server coded for TCP which functions perfectly fine, however, I want the client to also be able to use UDP with the server for none-important packets such as player location.

As of right now, this is my connect code for connected clients.

```
public void ConnectToServer(){
    tcp_client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
    tcp_client.Connect(server_ip, server_port);
    tcp_stream = new NetworkStream(this.tcp_client);

    this.udp_client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    this.udp_client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse(server_ip), server_port,new AsyncCallback(udp_connected), null);
}
```

Now the client isn't what I've had issues with for when I use `udp.Send(byteArray)` it appears to be sending as it's not throwing any exceptions but the server itself isn't responding to any data received.

*Please Note this is NOT 100% copy/pasted code. Alter to show just what's being an issue.*

```
private Socket c;
private UdpClient udp;
private isRunning = true;

public Client(Socket c){
    // This was accepted from TcpListener on Main Server Thread.
    this.c = c;
    this.networkStream = new NetworkStream(this.c);

    udp = new UdpClient();
    udp.Connect((IPEndPoint)c.RemoteEndPoint);

    // Then starts 2 thread for listening, 1 for TCP and 1 for UDP.
}

private void handleUDPTraffic(){
    IPEndPoint groupEP = (IPEndPoint)c.RemoteEndPoint;
    while (isRunning){
        try{
            byte[] udp_received = udp.Receive(ref groupEP);
            Console.WriteLine("Received UDP Packet Data: " + udp_received.Length);
        }catch{
            log.ERROR("UDP", "Couldn't Receive Data...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I right understand that you cannot make UDP client and server work together?

Comment: From my knowledge it is not possible to run TCP and UDP listening simultaneously on the same port. Generally, you can run only one protocol on a port. Change e.g. your UDP port number for listening and sending, then it should work.

Comment: @KBO See I wasn't sure because if you look at port-forwarding rules it allows the option of "Both" so I make the assumption that a single port can be used for UDP and TCP.

Comment: @Mattew: Sorry, my fault, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both TCP and UDP on the same port. See also:

[Can TCP and UDP sockets use the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437383/can-tcp-and-udp-sockets-use-the-same-port)

The sample below demonstrates that, you can simultaneously send and receive UDP and TCP messages.

Maybe, your UdpClient creation to listen for incoming datagrams is the problem. I recommend to create it once like your TcpListener.

The servers:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TCPUDPServer
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      TcpListener tcpServer = null;
      UdpClient   udpServer = null;
      int         port      = 59567;

      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Starting TCP and UDP servers on port {0}...", port));

      try
      {
        udpServer = new UdpClient(port);
        tcpServer = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

        var udpThread          = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(UDPServerProc));
        udpThread.IsBackground = true;
        udpThread.Name         = "UDP server thread";
        udpThread.Start(udpServer);

        var tcpThread          = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(TCPServerProc));
        tcpThread.IsBackground = true;
        tcpThread.Name         = "TCP server thread";
        tcpThread.Start(tcpServer);

        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to stop the servers.");
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Main exception: " + ex);
      }
      finally
      {
        if (udpServer != null)
          udpServer.Close();

        if (tcpServer != null)
          tcpServer.Stop();
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to exit.");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void UDPServerProc(object arg)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("UDP server thread started");

      try
      {
        UdpClient server = (UdpClient)arg;
        IPEndPoint remoteEP;
        byte[] buffer;

        for(;;)
        {
          remoteEP = null;
          buffer   = server.Receive(ref remoteEP);

          if (buffer != null && buffer.Length > 0)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("UDP: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
          }
        }
      }
      catch (SocketException ex)
      {
        if(ex.ErrorCode != 10004) // unexpected
          Console.WriteLine("UDPServerProc exception: " + ex);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("UDPServerProc exception: " + ex);
      }

      Console.WriteLine("UDP server thread finished");
    }

    private static void TCPServerProc(object arg)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("TCP server thread started");

      try
      {
        TcpListener server = (TcpListener)arg;
        byte[]      buffer = new byte[2048];
        int         count; 

        server.Start();

        for(;;)
        {
          TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

          using (var stream = client.GetStream())
          {
            while ((count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("TCP: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, count));
            }
          }
          client.Close();
        }
      }
      catch (SocketException ex)
      {
        if (ex.ErrorCode != 10004) // unexpected
          Console.WriteLine("TCPServerProc exception: " + ex);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("TCPServerProc exception: " + ex);
      }

      Console.WriteLine("TCP server thread finished");
    }
  }
}
```

The clients:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TCPUDPClient
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      UdpClient      udpClient = null;
      TcpClient      tcpClient = null;
      NetworkStream  tcpStream = null;
      int            port      = 59567;
      ConsoleKeyInfo key;
      bool           run = true;
      byte[]         buffer;

      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Starting TCP and UDP clients on port {0}...", port));

      try
      {
        udpClient = new UdpClient();
        udpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);

        tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);

        while(run)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Press 'T' for TCP sending, 'U' for UDP sending or 'X' to exit.");
          key = Console.ReadKey(true);

          switch (key.Key)
          {
            case ConsoleKey.X:
              run = false;
              break;

            case ConsoleKey.U:
              buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
              udpClient.Send(buffer, buffer.Length);
              break;

            case ConsoleKey.T:
              buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));

              if (tcpStream == null)
                tcpStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

              tcpStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Main exception: " + ex);
      }
      finally
      { 
        if(udpClient != null)
          udpClient.Close();

        if(tcpStream != null)
          tcpStream.Close();

        if(tcpClient != null)
          tcpClient.Close();
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to exit.");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that UDP cannot be assigned to a specific client?

Comment: I recommend to do several experiments. Use e.g. Wireshark to check, whether the UDP datagrams are really sent. Without the `UdpClient.Connect` call, you can use the returned remote endpoint from the `UdpClient.Receive` call to check/skip unwanted remote clients. You can store the allowed remote clients on the accepted TCP socket connections or so.