# C#: How to find an available port in a range of specific ports in TCP?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, ports

How do I find start listening to a port in **TCP protocol** within a **specific  range**?

For an example:

> Check the ports from 6001 to 7000 until you find an available one
>   and start listening to it when found.
>   when someone else tries the
>   same, he cannot listen to the same port.

Thank you.

Comment: [Find the next TCP port in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138043/find-the-next-tcp-port-in-net)

Comment: You just need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570098/in-c-how-to-check-if-a-tcp-port-is-available) and a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to perform that:

```
private static int initialPort = 6001; // initial port to search from

public static void StartServerTCP()
{
    bool serverSet = false;
    while (!serverSet && initialPort <= 7000)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Dns.GetHostName() + ": (Server:TCP) Trying to setup server at port: {0} [TCP]", initialPort);

            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(GetIP(), initialPort));
            serverSocket.Listen(0);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(Dns.GetHostName() + ": (Server:TCP) Server setup completed at port {0} [TCP]\n", initialPort);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            serverSet = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + Dns.GetHostName() + ": (Server:TCP) Port <{0}> is busy, trying a different one\n", initialPort);
            initialPort++;
        }
    }
}
```