# C# SocketException Can not connect because the target machine has actively declined the connection

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to write a chat client/server in c# locally to get familiar with Sockets.

First I start the server with (very simplified) following code:

**Server.cs**

```
    private readonly MessageManager _messageManager;
    private readonly ChatServer _chatServer;

    public ChatServerSkeleton()
    {
        _messageManager = new MessageManager();
        _chatServer = new ChatServer();
        Console.WriteLine("Server is running on: " + _messageManager.MyAddress);
    }
```

Then I start the Client with +- same way, except I store the serveraddress in the client (I copied the server address into a prompt).

**Client.cs**

```
    private readonly MessageManager _messageManager;
    public ChatClient ChatClient { get; }

    public ChatClientSkeleton(IPEndPoint serverAddress, string name)
    {
        _messageManager = new MessageManager();
        ChatClient = new ChatClient(new ChatServerStub(serverAddress, _messageManager), name);

        Console.WriteLine($"IPAddress of {name} is: {_messageManager.MyAddress}");
        Console.WriteLine($"IPAddress of Server is: { serverAddress}");
    }
```

**MessageManager.cs**

```
    private readonly TcpListener _serverSocket;
    public IPEndPoint MyAddress { get; }

    public MessageManager()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create server socket on random port
            _serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, FindFreeTcpPort());

            //Get host ip address
            IPAddress[] localIps = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress localhost = localIps.First(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

            //Get port of serversocket
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = _serverSocket.LocalEndpoint as IPEndPoint;
            int port = ipEndPoint.Port;

            //Create address
            MyAddress = new IPEndPoint(localhost, port);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Something went wrong with the serversocket:");
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
        } 
    }
```

FindFreeTcp port comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/150974/5985593

Everything up till now seems to work. Let's say for example the server has now **192.168.0.219:51080** and the client **192.168.0.219:51085**.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to send a message using this code in **MessageManager.cs**

```
    public void Send(MethodCallMessage message, IPEndPoint address)
    {
        try
        {
            _serverSocket.Start();
            TcpClient destination = new TcpClient(address.Address.ToString(), address.Port);
            NetworkStream output = destination.GetStream();
            MessageReaderWriter.Write(message, output);
            destination.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Failed to write a message:");
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            _serverSocket.Stop();
        }
    }
```

More specific on the *_server.Start();* line.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** it runs fine 1 time, when registering the client on the server. But after that if I want to send a message I get the SocketException where target machine actively refused.

I do use AcceptTcpClient() here:

**MessageManager.cs**

```
    public MethodCallMessage WReceive()
    {
        MethodCallMessage result = null;

        try
        {
            //_serverSocket.Start();
            TcpClient client = _serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream input = new NetworkStream(client.Client, true);
            result = MessageReaderWriter.Read(input);
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Failed to receive a message:");
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            //_serverSocket.Stop();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This method is used in the ServerSkeleton & ClientSkeleton as follows:

```
    public void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            MethodCallMessage request = _messageManager.WReceive();
            HandleRequest(request);
        }
    }
```

So the flow is basically as follows:

1. I start the server (instantiate new messagemanager, 3rd snippet
   and run serverskeleton (last snippet)
2. Server prints IP in
   console, i copy the ip & start the client
3. Instantiate client &
   set server ip to what I copy pasted
4. Start client skeleton (last
   snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TcpListener that has called Start() listens for incoming connections and then stacks them on a queue. Once that queue is full then a socket exception results. To remove connections from the queue you need to use the [AcceptTcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) or [AcceptSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocket(v=vs.110).aspx) methods of TcpListener. This then gives you a connection that you can send and receive data on.

What I am guessing may be happening is that you receive your first incoming client, but dont accept and remove it to send and receive data on, and your subsequent connections are refused as the pending queue list is full (this is just a guess).

There is an overloaded method ... [TcpListener.Start(int backlog)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kh8wf6s(v=vs.110).aspx) ... that allows you to set the size of the pending queue list (so you can have 5, 10 or more connections waiting to be accepted in the TcpListener)

With a server TCP socket the process is that you set it listening on a local address and a port. Clients then try to connect to that endpoint. When they connect the TCP listening socket accepts the connection and then passes that to a socket which is the socket on which data is transfered. The listening socket carries on listening for new connections, it doesnt itself transmit data.

I hope that makes sense ?

So the server would behave more like this ...

```
_serverSocket.Start();
TcpClient myAcceptedConnection = _serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
// in synchronous blocking socket situation the program flow halts 
// here til a connection is established
// once you have a connection ... do stuff with myAcceptedConnection
```

if you wished to avoid the blocking scenario you can use [TcpListener.Pending()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.pending(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if you have any connections waiting in the queue

EDIT 1:

Ok so the only weird thing I see is that you call the _serverSocket.Start() method in the MessageSend method ? A server doesnt normally start by sending out a message ... it normally waits listening for a connection, receives and reads the connection and then replies (or it might send out a greeting or such on connection).

Personally I would separate the listening aspect of the server from the sending and receiving of data ... have it in its own separate method, after all you want your server to be listening for incoming connections until you close it down. When you detect an incoming connection (perhaps by checking Pending() in a loop), then you can accept it and send and receive on the new TcpClient. When you are finished with whatever data you are transmitting/receiving on that client you can close it down , if thats what you want ... you dont need to close and open a tcp connection every time you send a message, you can leave it open til you are finished with it, in fact opening and closing tcp connections generates a bit of overhead in the handshake protocol that they go through.

There are caveats though ... Tcp connections can become "half open" especially with wireless which can lead to issues. Its a bit complicated to get into here, but I recommend this stellar set of articles by [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) as a good read through. Read the whole blog, as there is a ton of good info in there.

So, back to simple, I would have ...

1. A serverStart() method where you start your server listening.
2. A serverAccept() method where you check if you have any pending connections and accept them if they are there.
3. A clientConnect() method for your client where you connect to a server
4. Read() and Write() methods for the server and the client where you do the data transmission.

Normally the flow would be ...

1. Server Listens
2. Client Connects
3. Server Accepts
4. Client Sends
5. Server Receives
6. (then server sends/receives, client sends/receives)
7. everything closes and shuts down

Comment: Wow! Thanks! This does help a lot :D! I do use AcceptTcpClient() though, in a WReceive() Method that is called in a while(true) {}. (I'll add it to the Q) If I check with Pending() it shows indeed that after the first one there is still one pending. So does AcceptTcpClient() imply that the queue gets cleared? Otherwise I missed something, problem might be my project structure. I'll update the question but your answer helps a lot!

Comment: @JC97 AcceptTcpClient accepts and removes the first connection in the queue, if there is only one, then yes its cleared ... if there are more, then it just gets reduced by one. If you could show more of the code, like how you run your server and how you run your client I might be able to give more help. Incidentally I think that the default pending queue size in a TCP listening socket is 2 (off the top of my head anyway ... not entirely sure thats the case)

Comment: Added some more code. If it's not enough I'll upload a git repository somewhere

Comment: @JC97 added a reply, if you want you can post up to github and I can debug your code to see where its going wrong

Comment: I'll take a look at what you wrote, in the meantime I hosted it here: https://github.com/jclaessens97/Chat Thanks very much!

Comment: I took a look at the code. So a chat application joins and registers itself with the server. However currently when a chat application starts it creates a MessageManager object and starts running a TcpListner all of its own. Do you want to do that ? You might if you wanted to make chat applications peer to peer, the server simply holds the registered addresses and passes them to clients, but if you are doing this to learn about sockets you might be complicating things. A simpler solution would be to route messages through the server, then you wouldnt want ChatClients to start their own server.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm almost always overcomplicating things when I want to do something simple to learn. I'll start again & keep it simple then I guess ^^. Can you make the code I had work though? Or is it too much effort? I think I can learn from that as well :)

Comment: @JC97 I never got the socket error on the server at all, but no I couldnt get the clients to communicate with each other, but that was because they closed the connection to the server and then started up their own servers once they had registered themselves. So to go forward, I would keep connections open to the server, drop the server starting on the clients ... and then just send messages from the clients to the already open connection. The server then routes these messages to the clients that it has registered with it. (connections all remain open until applications are exited)