# Can I use the ScreenshotAsync method to save the screenshot to memory instead of disk?

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I am using PuppeteerSharp to generate a PDF from a locally-hosted HTML template, and want the PDF to be non-searchable, meaning that the PDF is truly just one big image within the PDF. I have chosen to take this approach because I want to make it harder for the document to be tampered with.

I have already come up with a technique for generating an image-only PDF. I access and take a screenshot of the HTML page, store it to disk, access said screenshot from the browser, and finally generate a PDF from that image. The PDF turns out fine, but I want to learn if it is possible to eliminate the need to store the image to disk.

Code below:

Function code

```
[FunctionName("pdftest")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Browser path: {appInfo.BrowserExecutablePath}");

            ViewPortOptions vprtOpts = new ViewPortOptions()
            {
                DeviceScaleFactor = 2
            };

            var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = true,
                ExecutablePath = appInfo.BrowserExecutablePath,
                DefaultViewport = vprtOpts
            });

            var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
            // access the HTML template
            await page.GoToAsync(@"C:\experiment\pdf\index.html");

            // where to save the screenshot
            var file = @"C:\experiment\pdf\index.png";

            // where to save the final PDF
            var file2 = @"C:\experiment\pdf\index2.pdf";
            PdfOptions opts = new PdfOptions()
            {
                PrintBackground = true,
                Width = "794px",
                Height = "1122px",
                Scale = 1
            };

            ScreenshotOptions scrOpts = new ScreenshotOptions()
            {
                FullPage = true,
            };

            await page.ScreenshotAsync(file, scrOpts);
            await page.GoToAsync(@"C:\experiment\pdf\index.png");
            var stream = await page.PdfStreamAsync(opts);
            await page.PdfAsync(file2, opts);
            await browser.CloseAsync();

            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var bfOptions = new BrowserFetcherOptions();
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            bfOptions.Path = Path.GetTempPath();
        }
        var bf = new BrowserFetcher(bfOptions);
        bf.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision).Wait();
        var info = new AppInfo
        {
            BrowserExecutablePath = bf.GetExecutablePath(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision)
        };

        var port = GetAvailablePort();
        info.RazorPagesServerPort = port;
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(info);

        var webHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                var scriptRoot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsScriptRoot");
                System.Console.WriteLine($"Starting web server on port {port}");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scriptRoot))
                {
                    webBuilder.UseContentRoot(scriptRoot);
                }

                webBuilder.UseUrls($"http://0.0.0.0:{port}")
                    .UseStartup<RazorPagesApp.Startup>();
            })
            .Build();

        webHost.Start();
    }

    private int GetAvailablePort()
    {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/150974/9035640
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
        listener.Start();
        int availablePort = ((IPEndPoint)listener.LocalEndpoint).Port;
        listener.Stop();
        return availablePort;
    }
}

public class AppInfo
{
    public string BrowserExecutablePath { get; set; }
    public int RazorPagesServerPort { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs you have [`ScreenShotDataAsync`](http://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_ScreenshotDataAsync_PuppeteerSharp_ScreenshotOptions_) which returns a `byte[]`:

```
byte[] data = await page.ScreenshotDataAsync(scrOpts);
```

There's also [`ScreenshotStreamAsync`](http://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_ScreenshotStreamAsync_PuppeteerSharp_ScreenshotOptions_) which returns a `Stream`:

```
Stream stream = await page.ScreenshotStreamAsync(scrOpts);
```